# Question mark usage

Tags: grammar, punctuation, questions

Should the sentence be:

> "What do you desire, I wonder?"

or

> "What do you desire, I wonder."

I know that it should be a period if you didn't invert the sentence but I'm not sure in this case. It might also be the that the whole sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I would match the punctuation of the closest statement, so I would use a period. But opinions may vary.

Comment: I wonder what you desire.

Comment: @user178049 — Since you asked, I desire users of this site to read and act on the injunction in the comment box not to answer questions in comments. At the simplest level, ask yourself how Noah or anyone else can tell whether Clare's response or your response is correct. It is not supported by evidence and nobody has the chance to vote it down. If Noah chooses one of these answers she cannot accept it, so nobody knows the question has been accepted or why.